# Why does list syntax after a header treat the contents as code?

Tags: github, markdown

I am relatively new to markdown but when I type in the following:

```
# Here is a header
    * here is some stuff about the header
    * some more stuff
```

And this gives me something like:
[image]
when I put it into github.

Why is this happening?

Comment: because you put 4 spaces in front of the asterisks. Remove the spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put 4 spaces in front of the asterisks. 4 leading spaces at the current indent level = code block. Remove the spaces (or put less then 4).

It's the same on stackoverflow

```
# Here is a header
    * here is some stuff about the header
    * some more stuff
```

produces

## Here is a header

```
* here is some stuff about the header
* some more stuff
```

where as

```
# Here is a header
* here is some stuff about the header
* some more stuff
```

produces

## Here is a header

- here is some stuff about the header
- some more stuff

as does

```
# Here is a header
   * here is some stuff about the header
   * some more stuff
```

--

## Here is a header

- here is some stuff about the header
- some more stuff